# creating a discord bot - problems with returning values

Tags: python, mysql, discord

I'm new to python and trying to create a discord bot that saves user input into an SQL database, which then can then recall later on.

I've got it saving and all is working there, the problem comes when the user tries to recall the data they have submitted, in that I can't get it to actually send the data in the variable, instead it just sends the variable name.

I cant seem to figure out why this is, regardless of my googling. Could someone help me out here? Code in question:

```
async def picks(ctx):
    cp1 = cursor.execute("SELECT currentpick1 FROM nascarpool WHERE id = '{ctx.author.id}'")
    cp2 = cursor.execute("SELECT currentlpick2 FROM nascarpool WHERE id = '{ctx.author.id}'")
    cp3 = cursor.execute("SELECT currentlpick3 FROM nascarpool WHERE id = '{ctx.author.id}'")
    cursor.execute(cp1, cp2, cp3)
    await ctx.send("You have registered the following picks: {cp1} {cp2}, and {cp3}")
    cursor.close
    mydb.close
```

Output is exactly as its typed, "You have registered the following picks: {cp1}, {cp2} and {cp3}"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Precede the quote with f for formatted string literals.
So you will have:

```py
await ctx.send(f"You have registered the following picks: {cp1} {cp2}, and {cp3}")
```

Comment: the ONLY thing i didnt try. thanks a bunch. now its spitting out "none, none, and none" instead of the int's stored, but that cant be too hard for me to figure out... thanks a bunch!